# Can't express router wait for a promise to resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

When I use the following code from express router

```
var anotherasyncfunction = async() => {
    var value = await settings.get("config"); // this is another async from a module.
    console.log(value);
}
app.get("/api", async(req, res) => {
    await anotherasyncfunction(); // This is another async function
    //more code
});
```

I get the below error.

**Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.**

When I remove the line

```
await anotherasyncfunction();
```

there is no error.

How to fix it? Can't I wait for a promise to resolve using await inside the express router?

Comment: can you share more detailed code?

Comment: updated to add a bit more code.

Comment: @Jack accept `req, res, next` or the express framework will move on to the next candidate route once the function exits. an `async` function exits at the first `await` statement, which is basically a `return` statement with an implicit promise that resolves when the asynchronous control flow is completed.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts does Jack need to send the response inside .then or .catch ?

Comment: @Jack can you also update code which send the response back ?

Comment: @mehta-rohan there's no `.then` or `.catch`... I don't understand what you're asking me.

Comment: 1. Could you show code with a 'res' object. It looks there is some important code still be hiden.

Comment: 2. Are there any middlwares running before app.get ?

Comment: That error means that you are trying to set headers on a response that you have already sent back to the client.

Comment: @Bogdan Surai yes, middleware is being used, and it sets some variables to the request, but I don't understand when the headers are sent, before it reaches the app.get() handler? I thought the headers will be sent only when response.send() is called inside the app handler.

Comment: Does 'anotherasyncfunction' do just those 2 rows in your real app?

Comment: yes, its a small function reading the value from settings (after awaiting) and then writing that to console.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in express-promise-router, it wraps the express router and lets you use async/await.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-promise-router